# swift set textfield input range number between 17 - 100

Tags: swift, validation, input, textfield

so i make a form that contain a bunch of data input from the user, on of the input is age, and i want the user to only input between 17 - 100.

after that i have this func that contain the validation of every textfield, so if the validation is correct it will make the button to enabled

this is my validation func :

```
func buttonReady() {
    
    if umurTextField.text != "" && domisiliTextField.text != "" && rencanaPembelianTextField.text != "" && luasTanahTextField.text != "" && luasBangunanTextField.text != "" && budgetTextField.text != "" && metodePembayaranTextField.text != "" && lantaiRumahTextField.text != "" {
        ButtonSearch.isEnabled = true
        ButtonSearch.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.5176470588, green: 0.3294117647, blue: 0.1333333333, alpha: 1)
        ButtonSearch.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0), for: .normal)
        ButtonSearch.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    }else {
        ButtonSearch.isEnabled = false
        ButtonSearch.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
        ButtonSearch.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        ButtonSearch.layer.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6666666667, green: 0.4745098039, blue: 0.2588235294, alpha: 0.4408410685)
    }
}
```

so far i just make the validation into not empty, but i want to make that "umurTextField" validation into only between 17 - 100, how do i do that?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be

```
if let res = umurTextField.text , 
   let value = Int(res), 
   (17...100).contains(value) , .......... {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can test if it is in the range using

```
17...100 ~= Int(umurTextField.text) ?? .min
```

Example

```
for test in ["8", "34", "b", "99", "104"] {
    print("\(test): \(17...100 ~= Int(test) ?? .min)")
}
```

> 8: false
> 34: true
> b: false
> 99: true
> 104: false